# Can I specify few fonts for a text in Indesign as in browsers?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am using scripts to fill Indesign document with text. There is standard unicode characters (emoji, cyrillic, maths, arabic) but sometimes they are are not in one font. I have to take it from different fonts.

Is there a solution like in browser CSS where i specify few fonts ordered by priority `font-family: font1, font2, font3`?

Comment: I am not sure that that font-family works on a character-by-character basis. It is more "use font1 to display the whole text if that exists, else fallback to font2, font3 etc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitively nothing like CSS font-styles enumeration but thanks to InDiScripts "IndyFont" a/o FontMixer from same Author to generate either a fully customized font or a composite font:
FontMixer : http://www.indiscripts.com/post/2013/07/fontmixer-extend-typefaces-in-indesign
InDyFont : http://www.indiscripts.com/category/projects/IndyFont